# Suma de resultados en un procedimiento MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento en una DB en MySQL:

```
  BEGIN
     SELECT(vista_detalle.numero,vista_detalle.id_empleado, vista_detalle.nombre,      
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN vista_detalle.tipo = 'S' AND  vista_detalle.estatus = 'F'
             THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
             END
          ) AS 'entrega'

        FROM db_becas.vista_detalle

WHERE DATE(vista_detalle.fecha_modificacion) BETWEEN fecha_inicial AND fecha_final
GROUP BY vista_detalle.id_empleado
ORDER BY vista_detalle.nombre
END
```

Y muestra la siguiente salida:

```
numero  id_empleado nombre                 entrega
333408  75  AARON RICARDO SOLIS PINEDA          10
314731  65  ALICIA LIZETH DOMINGUEZ ARELLANES   10
314405  45  ALMA RENATA FRAGOSO ARGUELLES       13
289411  80  ANA KAREN DE LA ROSA SAENZ           8
314645  63  ANA KARINA GARDEA RIVAS             10
314351  33  ANA LAURA MUÑOZ OJINAGA             11
327847  103 ANGEL ALBERTO RAMOS ROMAN            9
314699  37  ARMINE ARISVE AYALA RODRIGUEZ        6
496119  30  ARTURO GALLEGOS SALAS                2
335578  104 ARTURO GALLEGOS SALAS               10
314373  77  ATZIN DE JESUS SALDAÑO LUJAN         8
304411  115 BRENDA CRISTINA TERRAZAS ENRIQUEZ    2
304473  61  BRENDA JUDITH MONTES HOLGUIN        10
333481  34  BRIAN ABEL FLORES CALAHORRA         10
333433  69  BRYAN OBED OROZCO GUTIERREZ         10
305334  43  CARLOS CARRERA DELGADO              11
308841  35  CARLOS ULISES MONTES SALMERON        6
320702  93  CELESTINA MANCINAS LAREA             9
```

Como podria sumaar los resultados obtenidos en la columna 'entrega'?

Comment: Sumarlos todos? por grupos? como queres sumarlos?

Comment: Toda la columna entrega, poner un total.

Comment: con hacer un sum de esa columna alcanza..

Comment: Haz un SUM(nombre_columna) y tienes la suma total.

Comment: Aca el problema es que no es una tabla como tal, es decir los resultados de 'entrega' vienen desde el procedimiento antes escrito, el cual es generado por un contador que cuenta el numero de veces que ocurre cierta condición), ya había intentado con SUM('entrega') AS suma; pero todavía no he tenido éxito.